# Force K2 registration and profile views to be used instead of the default registration and profile views?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I converted a site from 1.7 to 2.5, and all is really just about done, but I'm having one issue. I want to use these two custom K2 templates that existed in the previous version for both user registration and user profile because they were using K2 as the user registration mechanism.

I've configured K2 to `Enable K2 User Profile`:

[image: Enable K2 User Profile]

but for whatever reason, when I navigate to `index.php?option=com_users&view=register` it's still grabbing the default registration form. Now, I thought it was maybe the URL, but the old 1.7 system is using the same URL. So, with some debugging I found that when the layout is told to search for a file, the K2 path isn't in the array.

What did I do wrong here?

**NOTE:** I also tried configuring the `User Manager` so that `Allow User Registration` was set to `No`, but I just get a `403` then because it's just not overriding with that K2 template.

[image: Allow User Registration]

## UPDATE

As I stated in the comments, for whatever reason I don't have a K2 registration menu item type. However, the weirdest part is that the 1.7 version didn't point to the K2 registration either.

A little more background. This is a really hacked together system. The menu is actually built with a Jumi module that is straight forward custom and when the user is logged in the link that is used for the profile for example is this:

```
index.php?option=com_users&view=user&layout=form&id=3
```

and the register link, which is also custom (i.e. it's a link on a custom view) is this:

```
index.php?option=com_user&view=register
```

So, in short, I don't know enough about the Joomla navigation system to understand how to get those links to reroute to the K2 views that reside `/components/com_k2/templates` folder.

## UPDATE

I put the `register.php` view that existed in `/components/com_k2/templates` folder into the `/templates/tmplname/html/com_users/register` folder and renamed it `default.php` so that the default user registration navigation would choose that view. And it did choose that view, no real surprise, but it also failed on a line like this:

```
<?php if(count(array_filter($this->K2Plugins))): ?>
```

because `K2Plugins` is `null` and that's not allowed for the `array_filter` function. I'm guessing this is because if this view were inside the `com_k2` folder, like its original location, this would be available. I'm trying everything I can think of now.

It also threw on this line:

```
$this->K2Params->get('recaptchaOnRegistration')
```

because `K2Params` is null so of course `get` isn't available.

Comment: Try going to edit the menu item that is associated with the registration form, go to change the "type" and set it to the K2 registration form

Comment: @Lodder, I don't see a K2 registration form menu item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, finally! The `/plugins/system/k2/k2.php` was catching the `onAfterDispatch` method for the navigation of `com_users`. If it was `com_users` and `register` or `profile` then it redirected and leveraged a different view. Well, the problem was that the old code said `com_user` instead of `com_users`. Silly!